# how to Restric user to do infinite registrations by setting value of $_POST[] array from browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication

I have 2 pages
Page 1

```
     <span id="error"></span
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
     <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
     <input type="button" value="register" id="reg"/>

     <script>
     var email_r=$('#email').val();
     var pass_r=$('#pass').val();
     $('#reg').on('click', function(){
      $('#error').load('register.php',{ email:email_r , pass: pass_r });
});
     </script>
```

Page 2
 on page 2 I check unique email Id and registration is done,
**anyone** can set the value through browser and perform infinite registration bomb,
how can I secure my login process that will restrict user to misuse it?

Comment: Hi, arent you checking if that email already exist? and arent the registration details been sent to the email?

Comment: I made clear about unique email

Comment: written on page 2,i want to secure it before sending email

Comment: Consider setting registered cookie as minimal security.

Comment: I advised to use `human verification` on your site..

Comment: yes I can use captcha but ultimately he can open register.php and setting up values through browser.

Comment: `$_POST[]` is very secure, user cannot set it by itself!!
If you not define any other way to set it..@user3340696

Comment: You can make use of the IP. Set a time limit of n seconds between registration from a single IP. You'll need to store the IP used for previous registrations and then whenever a new registration request comes, query your DB for the IP and check if the timestamp is older than n seconds or not.

Comment: @AshishMishra That is true but someone can misuse the registration process by creating another script that calls page2 with as many parameters as they want.

Comment: IP mask, any solution from php, rather dwelling up from the database??

Comment: @Akshat Singhal, So that's why i told to use `human verification`,its the right way...to secure our sites !!And if using `$_POST[]` then only the way to make it bomb ,if the hacker or user knows the variables define in `register.php`

Comment: Use `human verification` on your `register.php` then your problem may be solved !!@user3340696

Comment: can google recapta be user on two pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there is no easy solution to prohibit malicious activities. You always have to leave the possibility to use the site (since it is the reason you implemented it at first) and this leaves room for malicious activities. You have to differentiate the malicious requests from the "good" requests. This is not easy.

You might search for "captcha" or "honeypot" on the internet and implement an own solution or use an existing one (e.g. http://areyouahuman.com). This is a topic which cannot be answered in one sentence and there is no fits-all solution.
If you have no clue at all and do not want to invest too much time, I would recommend searching for an open ready-to-use captcha provider. There are some out there, although I cannot recommend one. These are easy to integrate and provide a good basis.

If your problem is more like a DOS (denial of service) "attack" (like 10 registrations per second), you might search for this keyword. This topic is even more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using just javascript as a security feature why not try to use some PHP as well.

here is something to get you started.

> `http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL`

This isnt all secure but once you get the jits of it , you will understand security parameters required

Hope this helps